# How to start vim in "private mode"

Tags: vim, privacy

Modern browsers have a feature called "private mode" or "incognito mode". I am trying to do the same thing with vim, i.e. run it in way that no traces of my activities are left behind. This way I would be able to e.g. use vim to open a file containing sensitive information stored in an encrypted volume without having to worry that any information will be leaked.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
alias vim_private="vim -i NONE --cmd 'set noswapfile' --cmd 'set nobackup'"
```

I have that in my .bashrc.
Rationale for the above:

- `-i NONE` so that no filenames or register contents are leaked through .viminfo
- `--cmd 'set noswapfile'` is to prevent the creation a swap file
- `--cmd 'set nobackup'` for no backup files

Is there is anything else that I'm missing? Are there any other ways that vim could leak information?

Comment: I believe you are fine: `-i -NONE` starts in `compatible` mode so you are supposed to have no history or viminfo.

Comment: To be sure, you could also add `-u NONE -U NONE`. Do you also require that files Vim accesses keep all their last access/modified dates?

Comment: Very useful when one mistakenly types a password/passphrase directly in a terminal and wants to clean `$HISTFILE` without moving the sensitive data to the `.viminfo`. By the way, is this the only place(plus swp files) where traces could be stored by vim?

Comment: Suggestion for alias name: `vimcognito`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your settings look fine. I'm not sure whether plugins will be loaded when you invoke Vim as `vi`, but several plugins (that e.g. provide MRU functionality) will store information (usually in `~/.vim...` files), too. Their load can be avoided through `--noplugin`.

Also, for the paranoid, `$VIMINIT`, `:set exrc`, and `:set modeline` can lead to Vimscript code being executed; this could (re-)enable privacy-relevant options.

Comment: So what would be the full tinfoil hat mode?  add  --noplugin, clear $VIMINIT, and :set noexrc and :set nomodeline ?

Comment: @tuxayo: The "full tinfoil" would compile his own stripped-down version of Vim (vi?) that doesn't read any RC file, and also has `:!`, `system()` and related commands disabled.

Comment: I tested that in vim 8.1, when I use `-u DEFAULTS -U DEFAULTS` which use defaults vim settings without user's file, `$VIMINIT` has no effect. And `noexrc` & `nobackup` are the defaults. Thus, `:set noexrc` and clearing `$VIMINIT` is no need. I think just add an extra `--cmd 'set nomodeline'` to the above. My version is `vim -i NONE -u DEFAULTS -U DEFAULTS -n -c 'set nomodeline'` (`-c` == `--cmd`; `-n` for no swap file; `-u DEFAULTS` will not load plugin too)

Answer (score 0):

The alias presented by OP will not work depending on what commands you have in your vimrc file. This is because `--cmd` runs commands before your vimrc file is loaded, and so your vimrc file could overwrite these values. Instead you could you can use `-c` which is the same except is executed after your vimrc file is loaded.

Since there are many options in your vimrc that could leak data, it's probably better to use a different approach.

**Use vim with a default vimrc file**

Like was suggested above, another alternative is to use an alias to load vim with the default rc file with:

```bash
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace # don't store commands that start with space to the history file
alias pvim_default=' vim -u DEFAULTS -U DEFAULTS -i NONE -n -c "set nomodeline"'
```

We can set the bash `HISTCONTROL` variable to `ignorespace` option so that any command prefixed by a space is not saved to the bash history file.  In zsh, use `setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` instead.

**Load vim with your own vimrc file**

If you still want to load your vimrc, a more flexible alternative would be to pass a custom variable `g:PrivateMode` to vim, which you can use to configure you vimrc file as necessary.

```bash
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace # don't store commands that start with space to the history file
alias pvim=' vim --noplugin --cmd "let g:PrivateMode=1"'
```

Then in your vimrc use

```
" Don't use private mode if g:PrivateMode is not set from the command line
" Put near start of vimrc file
if !exists("g:PrivateMode")
    g:PrivateMode = 0
endif


" Put this near the end of your vimrc file so values don't get overwritten by accident
if g:PrivateMode
    set nobackup
    set noundofile
    set noswapfile
    set viminfofile=NONE
    set viminfo=
    set nomodeline
    set noexrc " dont load .vimrc, .exrc, .gvimrc found in the current directory
    set clipboard^=exclude: " make sure vim isn't saving to system clipboard
else
    " setup for non-private mode
endif
```

You'll want to look over your vimrc file to see if there's any commands, plugins, etc that may end up leaking data and disabling them in private mode.